# Is it possible to disconnect a client mid-request?

Tags: fiddler

I'm trying to simulate the situation where a client is sending a large POST request to the server and the server (or a load balancer) terminates the client connection halfway through the request. 
Is this possible to do with Fiddler? I'm open to other (Windows) tool suggestions as well.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Click Rules > Customize Rules. Scroll to the **OnPeekAtRequestHeaders** function. Add code like so:

```
static function OnPeekAtRequestHeaders(oSession: Session) {

    if (oSession.uriContains("myupload.php") && 
        oSession.oRequest.headers.Exists("Content-Length") && 
        oSession.oRequest.headers["Content-Length"] != "0")
    {
        oSession.oRequest.pipeClient.EndWithRST();
    }
}
```

Comment: This works great, thanks! Is there any way to control when the reset happens? For example, any way to make a rule that resets the connection after 1Mb has been transferred.

Comment: Not really, no. You could queue a timer to do it after a specified period of time. Or you could build an application atop FiddlerCore and use the OnReadRequestBuffer event, but this event isn't exposed in Fiddler itself.